# Building a Query URL for Places API in Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use Places API by using an URL but I couldn't find any ways to build a query string for Places API on Google's documentation. (which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide))

Using the API key is not a problem, I just need to get the results which I get from nearbySearch by using a URL and `fetch` method in Javascript.

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

Is there any way that I can build a query string to retrieve json data for Places API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: string concatenation?

Comment: The thing is I don't know which "base" url I need to work with. Adding parameters to it should not be a big problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to know. Its wrapped in the PlacesService class - see example here; https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: Yes, I can work with the api itself but we're trying to switch to another API that only takes requests with URL so I want to change my way of handling nearbySearch to adapt faster in the future when the change is done. URL string was defined in another page. Posted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly the base url is not showed on the URL page, it's actually in [this page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). 
Any request can be done with the urls in that page.